# Mount shared drive on Mac

Tags: macos, mount, nas

I have currently added a shared drive to my "load at login" window for my user.
Now this does automatically mount the drive when logging in however it also immediately loads up a finder window with the shared drives contents. This is after I have ticked to hide the item on load as well.

Can anyone tell me why its loading its still loading a finder window with the shared drives contents and how I could stop this behaviour at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just how Mac handles the shared folder connection, I can't really tell you more than that as that is all I know on that matter.

If that is the only thing that is bothering you then there are some scripts posted that may help you out.

Link to Article: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18522/mounting-shares-with-login-items-at-login-finder-windows-popup